# How can I get GCC to place a C++ constexpr in ROM?

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, constexpr

I compile for LPC1114, a small ARM (actually Cortex) target. RAM is much more limited than ROM. I use the latest Mentor (CodeBenchLite) GCC compiler (GCC 4.6.3). I have some constant objects that I'd like to have in ROM. As far as I understand the ffx object in the code below should end up in ROM (code), but instead it is placed in DATA.

```
class flop {
    public:
       int x;
       constexpr flop( int x ) : x(x){}
};

 extern constexpr flop ffx( 1 );
```

How can I convince the compiler to pre-compute the object and place it in ROM?

or maybe I should ask:

- can I somehow expect the G++ compiler to generate ROMable data for ffx
- if so, is my code correct for this
- if so, for which G++ version is this supported (I use 4.6, maybe I need 4.7?)

=======================================

This bugzilla entry [c++/49673](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gcc.bugs/325422) seems to indicate that mine is a known problem, probably fixed in GCC 4.7. Unfortunately I prefer to use the Mentor/CodeSourcery built, which is still at 4.6.3. So I guess for the time being I am  stuck with the bug. :(

Comment: I don't know the architecture, but doesn't it seem an oxymoron to try to *write* to *read-only* memory?

Comment: @JohnDibling: it seems like it, but you'd be wrong.  Small processors often have a way to flash your program to ROM.

Comment: There's nothing that the C++ standard will give you. However, you can possibly try *scatterloading* as described here: [Locating code and data in memory (Scatterloading)](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3558.html). HTH!

Comment: @JohnD : no-one is writing to ROM. The ffx object is a constant, and the constexpr assures that it can be initialized at compile-time. So the compiler can (should??) pre-compute the value and put it in a romable section. Instead it reserves RAM and creates initialization code.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: Aha, thanks for the elaboration.

Comment: I just tried this with gcc 4.6.3 on x86 Linux using `-std=c++0x`, and I definitely see the value of `ffx` statically initialized in the `.data` segment there. So on at least this platform, the value _is_ pre-computed as you want ...

Comment: @ (definitely-not-)Useless : I re-checked, and I was partially wrong - it ends up in .data allright, and there is no initialization code. *but* it should be in some rommable segment, probably .rodata , how else is the linker to know that it can be put in ROM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Update #2: *Test results with gcc 4.7.0*

This is indeed fixed in gcc 4.7.0. Your code produces the following assembler output:

```
    .file   "constexpr.cpp"
    .globl  _ffx
    .section .rdata,"dr"
    .align 4
_ffx:
    .long   1
```

which is what you probably want. Upgrading?

I think you need a platform specific solution for this. See [Locating code and data in memory (Scatterloading)](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3558.html):

> Scatterloading allows you to partition an application into a number of separate code and data regions spread throughout the address map. The location of these regions can differ between load time and run time:
>
> 1. Load Regions contain application code and/or data used by the application at power-on/load time (typically ROM).

Instead of relying on gcc alone, try to make use of `armlink` as suggested in the link provided above.

Update: I saw the gcc bug you've noted. LLVM/MinGW is equally hopeless. However, I've been playing around with GCC 4.6 and here's something I think *may* help you:

```
struct Data
{
    int i;    
};
constexpr Data getData() { return Data{1}; }
```

If instead of having a ctor, you have a `constexpr` function, and try to generate the assembler output, the output will typically be empty (no `.data` sections). And if you use this to initialize some variable (in global scope) as below:

```
const Data foo = getData();
```

you'd get an assembly as follows:

```
    .file   "constexpr.cpp"
    .section .rdata,"dr"
    .align 4
__ZL3foo:
    .long   1
```

(this is with `g++ -std=c++0x -S` command line). Does that work for you?

Comment: See my comment on the Travis' answer (and I edited the question): the problem is that the compiler is reserving RAM and generating initialization code, instead of generating initialized constant data.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: I think it could be related to the fact that a ctor is a special member function and the compiler generates that bit of code to make sure all goes well. Does the output change with optimization flags turned on (I don't think it would but I guess it's worth a try). Anyway, I updated my answer with my latest investigations and it may help you.

Comment: Yes, that does end up in .rodata, but it does not help me much: the code I showed is a simplified example, I need a class object with a non-trivial (but still constexpr) ctor. Thanks for checking LLVM.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: I just tested with gcc 4.7.0 and it looks like they have a fixed implementation for `constexpr` constructors!

Comment: Thanks, that does not solve it for me immedeiately but at least I know my code is correct and that it will solve the problem one day.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: *Related* I had shot an email to the clang-dev ML and you may want to pick up on it someday -- [here](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/static-initialization-of-global-namespace-scope-constexpr-objects-td4024433.html). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, `const` data is placed into a read-only section, so all the data in this section can go into ROM (or be programmed into FLASH).

The GCC linker instruction file (*.ld), can assign addresses to different sections.

Another alternative is to place large data structures (such as fonts) into assembly language.  The assembly language can place the data into segments easier than the C or C++ langauge can.

One our next objectives is to separate the data from our executable.  This shortens the executable and reduces testing time on the executable.

Comment: A const object that has a (non-trivial?) initializer will not be placed in ROM. One of the reasons for constexpr is (as far as I understand) to make this possible, but it does not seem to happen for me. (constexpr is a C++0x09/11 construct that is stronger than (and implies) const).